# Three.js - Detect collision by raycasting from a Group

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am creating an endless runner game in which a character on a skateboard is static at (0,0,0) and the scenery moves towards that point and is reset to the "back" when it is off screen.

The aim of the game is to dodge cars coming towards you and collect objects that move slower than the cars towards the character, both gaining you points. I am using `THREE.Raycaster` to detect collision between the skateboard and the cars/objects (different collision scenarios for the cars & objects) which I have got working well.

**The Problem**

I am detecting collision between the skateboard and the objects because the skateboard extends further than the character in the `-z` direction (where the objects are coming from) and so it is first to "hit" an object. The skateboard is a group of objects (Still a `THREE.Object3D` and not a `THREE.Group()`, but they function the same) containing for example 4 wheels, two trucks, etc... and so I cannot use the main `SkateBoardGroup` object to detect collision as it is not a `Mesh` and does not have vertices, which are what determines where the rays are cast from.

The closest `Mesh` to the objects is the `SkateBoardBaseRight` `Mesh`, which is a child of the SkateBoardBase object (containing 3 Meshes), which itself is a child of the main `SkateBoardGroup` object. I am currently accessing this `Mesh` with the following code and raycasting from that `Mesh`:

```
objectMesh = SkateBoardGroup.children[0].children[2];
```

*I want to be able to raycast from the top level `SkateBoardGroup` as there are times in which the skateboard rotates and so the `SkateBoardBaseRight` mesh is not closest to the object.*

**What I want**

I would appreciate an explanation and/or code example of how I can raycast from the `THREE.Object3D` `SkateBoardGroup` rather than having to dive into the children of an object.

*Setting the `raycaster.intersetObjects` to recursive is not what I'm looking for as that is for the objects the skateboard collides with.*

**Here is my raycasting code:**

I am calling this function twice, once for the cars and once for the other objects

`originObject` is the `SkateBoardGroup`, `collidedObjects` is the array containing either the cars or the other objects, and `doesCollidedObjectsEndGame` is a boolean flag to decide which type of object is it (car or other object)

```
let cooldown = false; // cooldown reset when try-again clicked
let cooldown2 = false;

function detectCollisionRaycaster(originObject, collidedObjects, 
doesCollidedObjectsEndGame) {

let objectMesh = originObject.children[0].children[2];

let originPoint = originObject.position.clone();

if (cooldown === false) {
    for (var vertexIndex = 0; vertexIndex < objectMesh.geometry.vertices.length; vertexIndex++) {
        var localVertex = objectMesh.geometry.vertices[vertexIndex].clone();
        var globalVertex = localVertex.applyMatrix4( objectMesh.matrix );
        var directionVector = globalVertex.sub( objectMesh.position );

        var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster( originPoint, directionVector.clone().normalize() );
        var collisionResults = raycaster.intersectObjects( collidedObjects, true );
        if ( collisionResults.length > 0 && collisionResults[0].distance < directionVector.length()) {
            if (doesCollidedObjectsEndGame) {
                // car objects collided
                gameIsOver = true;
                cooldown = true;
            } else {
                if (cooldown2 === false) {
                    cooldown2 = true;
                    // other objects collided
                    setTimeout(function(){
                        cooldown2 = false;
                    }, 100);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Commenting cause not really an answer, just advice: for a good experience and gameplay that feels tight, balanced, and responsive, you should have an underlying idealised model of the obstacles and the player (e.g. a 2D grid), ticking at a constant rate. This should then be used to calculate what to display and where to display it. The implementation is much simpler, and offers you more options to finetune collision conditions.

Comment: @AurelBílý Thanks for your comment but it is not really related to what I am asking, I have the collision working and the game functions perfectly, I am just having a problem with understanding how I can raycast from a `THREE.Object3D()` which does not have an vertices itself rather than having to raycast from one of the child Meshes of that `Object3D`

Comment: I understand, which is why it is just a comment. :)

Comment: @AurelBílý Well thank you for the advice, I will definitely look into it!